# SSJS script to update Salesforce object

Tags: ssjs, marketing-cloud

How to update Salesforce object (eg. contact or lead) from Salesforce Marketing Cloud using Server Side Javascript ?

Answer (score 2):

Not at the moment, no.  But you can use SSJS to to build the [**AMPScript function calls**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_functions_for_use_with_salesforcecom/) and then use [**TreatAsContent()**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions2/treatascontent3/#TreatAsContent) to force them to evaluate.

Comment: Can this be used Automation Studio as  script activity ?

Comment: Yes, you can use it in an Automation.