# Load data into Salesforce object from Marketing Cloud data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforce1-app, dataextensions, marketing-cloud-connect

Could you please help me to solve my problem? I have to upload the data from a Marketing Cloud data extension to a CRM object. How I can achieve this if my Marketing Cloud and CRM are integrated with the connector?

Your help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it in bulk, e.g iterating through 10.000 records in a Data Extension, and upsert data to Sales Cloud, you should be using it's [Bulk API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_intro.htm)

With regards to the use of SSJS with REST, there are numerous examples here on SFSE, a.o.:

[Making a REST API call from a Script Activity in Automation Studio](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/224218/making-a-rest-api-call-from-a-script-activity-in-automation-studio)

[REST API Methods in AMPScript or SSJS](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/204006/rest-api-methods-in-ampscript-or-ssjs)

You can use AmpScript function: [UpdateSingleSalesforceObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/updatesinglesalesforceobject.htm) and either execute it from an email, Cloud Page, or wrap it in SSJS, if you want to use it in Automation Studio - the latter as suggested here by Adam Spriggs:
[SSJS script to update Salesforce object](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/146513/ssjs-script-to-update-salesforce-object) . This function works on any objects - both standard and custom, so I assume it will also be able to update your Veeva data.

Using UpdateSingleSalesforceObject will not count towards your API limits on Sales Cloud.

Comment: Thanks @Lukas to give some hint. I may not have to upload the bulk data.. we want to upload suggestions into Veeva CRM Suggestion object. Any idea, is this possible through bulk API to load the data into veeva suggestion object or any other simple solution.

Comment: Thanks for some more context. I have updated my answer to reflect that

Comment: Thank you @Lukas for such explanation. Will try for the above approach to get the task done.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [CreateSalesforceObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/createsalesforceobject.htm) using AMPscript for this.

Yet, it is not recommended to store the data in Sales Cloud.

Comment: Thank you @Selim. Is there any other way like can use Rest/Soap APIs or any other recommended solution?

Comment: @Selim: Why is it not recommended to store data in SC?

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained it much more. I meant, because it is expensive to store data in SalesCloud, people prefer storing data in Marketing Cloud.